# How to add to google app engine flask website the user registration ability if it wasn't scheduled in application architecture

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I created website-app for myself and it become really useful and many peoples wont also use it. But user management was not scheduled in application architecture. Is there any way to easy add user registration so each user would have his own google database tables but with same name?
example of one "table":

```
class Settings(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty()
    link = db.LinkProperty()
    rating = db.StringProperty()
```

How can I separate data from this "table" between different users? I search for some kind of wrapper so I don't need to change current architecture.

Comment: You have to remember there is no concept of tables with the datastore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember there is no concept of tables with the datastore so you can't have a separate set of tables for each user as such.

You have a few choices,  the two I would investigate are

1. create a separate app with the existing code base and each user runs their own site. You may not need to do any code changes at all
2. If you want complete separation of data for each user in a single app then look at namespaces (thats how multi-tenancy is normally implemented.)

However you haven't really provided a clear definition of how you want to separate the users etc.. so there a probably other approaches you can take.

Comment: "each user runs their own site" - this. I wont to make something like this. Is there way to add registration where user can choose subdomain: user1.myapp.com where he got his own copy of website. Or some other workaround maybee?

Answer (score 0):

Short of having a copy of the database for each user; you'll have to implement some code changes.

The easiest one you can do is add a foreign key to your data tables that points to your user table; then you filter all records based on this foreign key.

Once you have that change, you can write a [view decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/) that will automatically filter the records for you.